# How to execute a method for the active button in the list using typescript and react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

i have items with add button listed in a dialog. when one add button in list is clicked it wil be active and clicking button for other item in list will make it active. Basically most recent clicked button in list will be active.

below is the picture of add buttons in list

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

below is my code,

```
function Dialog({items}: Props){
    return (
        <List items={items}/>
    );
}

function List({items}: Props);
    const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = React.useState();
    return (
        items.map((item: any, index: number) => {
            <Card>
                <AddButton
                    index={index} 
                    isActive={activeIndex===index}
                    setActiveIndex={setActiveIndex}
                />
            </Card>
        }
    );
}



function AddButton ({isActive, setActiveIndex, index}: Props) {
    const {toggleDrawing} = useDrawing(item);
    const handleClick = () => {
        setActiveIndex(index);
        if (isActive) { //if button is active then only call toggleDrawing and it doesnt work
            toggleDrawing();
        }
    }
    return (
        <IconButton 
            active={isActive}
            onClick={handleClick}
        />
   );
```

}

The above code, properly makes the respective button active in list. but it doesnot call toggleDrawing method for the button clicked.

what i want is when user clicks add button on one item in list then this should become active and toggleDrawing and when user clicks another button in list then toggleDrawing for previous should be stopped and this button should be active and toggleDrawing should start for this button

how can i do it?
could someone help me with this. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. use `React.useEffect` that listens to changes in the active prop of the AddButton and then toggle your drawing.

```
function Dialog({items}: Props){
    return (
        <List items={items}/>
    );
}

function List({items}: Props);
    const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = React.useState();
    return (
        items.map((item: any, index: number) => {
            <Card>
                <AddButton
                    index={index} 
                    isActive={activeIndex===index}
                    setActiveIndex={setActiveIndex}
                />
            </Card>
        }
    );
}



function AddButton ({isActive, setActiveIndex, index}: Props) {
    const {toggleDrawing} = useDrawing(item);
    const handleClick = () => {
        setActiveIndex(index);
    }

    React.usEffect(() => {
      if (isActive) {
          toggleDrawing();
      }

   }, [isActive]);

    return (
        <IconButton 
            active={isActive}
            onClick={handleClick}
        />
   );
```

Comment: thanks. but i am using the state for active index to track the list item that is currently clicked